# Mongoose models not staying connected in experimental "app" Next.js 13

Tags: mongoose, next.js, next.js13

EDIT SOLVED: I created a new Nextjs app and didn't use the experimental "app" folder structure. This apparently also switches everything back to the previous "handler" api functions that you can put a switch or if statement into. It appears that this setup is stable and works. The bleeding edge latest version of Nextjs doesn't seem to work with database connections yet.

OP:

When I've copied this [dbConnect file](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-mongodb-mongoose/lib/dbConnect.js) into my typescript Next.js 13 app, it's not behaving as expected when I hit the api endpoint.

I'm using the latest verion of Next.js with the new "experimental" app folder. It appears these individual POST, GET, etc functions are also part of the latest Nextjs release. My login_admin api route file looks like this:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import Admin from '@/models/Admin'
import dbConnect from '@/lib/dbConnect'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

export async function POST(request: Request) {
    const conn = await dbConnect()
    console.log(conn.connection.readyState)
    const data = await request.json()
    const { username, password } = data
    const admin = await Admin.findOne({ username: username })
    if (admin) {
        if (await admin.verifyPW(password)) {
            return NextResponse.json(admin)
        } else {
            return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Password incorrect' })
        }
    } else {
        return NextResponse.json({ error: 'No admin found with that username'})
    }
}
```

I his this api endpoint usually once after I start the server, and it might complete then a few times, but if I change anything in any of my files, or just wait long enough, I can't hit the endpoint anymore. If I console log the connection readyState returned by dbConnect, it returns 1, and then after a few moments my findOne method buffer times out:

```
error - MongooseError: Operation `admins.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:145:33)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
```

I feel like it's something to do with the way Nextjs caches, and maybe even specifically to version 13, but I'm not sure. Does anyone know if the vercel github examples I linked to above are for version 13 or 12? I'm running everything in Ubuntu, btw, if that makes any difference.

Comment: You should check the connection state of the one returned by `dbConnect`: `const conn = await dbConnect(); console.log(conn.readyState);`. Can you post the end-point code?

Comment: I've updated the question to check this instead. It is returning 1, but I'm still getting the same buffer timeout error. Tbc, I've used mongoose with nextjs 12 before and it's worked fine.